# Чтение txt из интернета

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Как прочитать txt файл из интернета и записать его содержимое в переменную на node.js

```
const http = require('http');

http.get('http://hexando.me/projects/fc/status.txt', (res) => {
  let data = String();

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

});

fc.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content == "fc status") {
    message.reply(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: `new String()` лучше заменить на ''

Comment: что за `fc`? и в чем именно сложность?

Comment: 1. Вынести data за пределы замыкания. Иначе ее не будет видно в `fc.on ...` 2. Добавить в замыкание `res.on('end' ...` иначе как понять, что данные засосались все? @see [документацию](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)